# How can i stop a UI from flickering with unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Anyone know how i can stop this from flicking basically I'm doing a raycast and if it hits the crafting table it it shows up a text saying press e to craft but it is flickering cause its in the void update function but if anyone knows a work around that would be nice thanks!

```cs
if(hit.collider.tag == "CraftingTable")
{
    if(textIsOn)
    {
        noshowcraftingtext();
    }
    else
    {
        showcraftingtext();
    }
}
```

```cs
void showcraftingtext()
{
    textIsOn = true;
    pressEToShowCraftingTableUI.SetActive(true);
}

void noshowcraftingtext()
{
    textIsOn = false;
    pressEToShowCraftingTableUI.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: You're toggling `textIsOn` each frame as long as `hit.collider.tag` is `"CraftingTable"`. It's not flickering - it's being disabled & re-enabled over and over again.

Comment: ahhhh ok would their be a way then where it toggles off when your not hitting it i got it to activate when hitting it but not disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem of your code is that you are trying to change the state after state was changed.

That's why updated isn't the case in a big project, because all such things will lead to unpredictable or logically conflicted behavior, to avoid this you should use Data driven approach instead.

But to fix exactly your issue, you need to have a function, which isn't based on the state of the object, but returns what should happen right now.

There isn't much about what's going on inside your game, but I can guess that you are firing a raycast with mouse and then checking is it craftable or not.

```cs
public void Raycaster : MonoBehavior {

 public void YourClickMethod()
 {
   if(hit.collider.tag == "CraftingTable")
     {
       hit.collider.GetComponent<UserInputReceiver>().SetClicked(this);
     }
 }
}
```

And on the object which is receiving your raycast you should add this:

```cs
public class UserInputReceiver : MonoBehavior {
   private bool _isEnabled = false;
   //set this inside inspector
   public GameObject ObjectToEnable;
   private Raycaster _currentSender = null
   public void SetClicked(Raycaster sender){
      _isEnabled = !_isEnabled;
      _currentSender = sender;
   }
   public void Update(){
     if(_currentSender != null && _isEnabled) {
      _isEnabled = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _currentSender.transform.position) < 1f; //set the threshold based on your unit system
     }
     //or another object, you can put it inside public field and enable him
     //gameObject.SetActive(_isEnabled);
     objectToEnable.SetActive(_isEnabled); //here you can pass a reference through inspector for your canvas

   }
}
```

This is how you can outstand this issue with a short way.
This code will set the flag based on the received input and the distance. If you need to keep enabled text forever, than remove distance check than it will enable only with a second click, without distance dependency.